# Better code then a regex sub() python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find out if there are better faster ways to clean this returned string. Or is this the best way. It works, but more efficient ways are always wanted.

I have a function that returns the following output:

```
"("This is your:, House")"
```

I clean it up before printing with:

```
a = re.sub(r'^\(|\)|\,|\'', '', a)
print a

>>> This is your: House
```

I also learn a lot from the different ways people do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expression to do this.

```
>>> import string
>>> a = '"("This is your:, House")"'
>>> ''.join(x for x in a if x not in string.punctuation)
'This is your House'
```

---

```
>>> tbl = string.maketrans('', '')
>>> a.translate(tbl, string.punctuation)
'This is your House'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='"("This is your:, House")"'
s.replace('\"','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace(':','')
'This is your House'
```